# PHP & MYSQL-How to search words and put them like a sentence for translation?

Tags: php, mysql, search, translation

I am creating where a user can search like `"How are you"` and it outputs the translation to `"Como son tu"`

```
My database looks like this

English         Translation
How             Como
Are             Son
You             Tu
```

MY CODE:

```
if(($_POST['translateKey'])){
  $translateWord = mysql_fix_string($connection, $_POST['translateWord']);
  if (!empty($translateWord)) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $username";
    $result = $connection->query($query);

    if (!$result) {
        if (!$result) die("Couldn't query data: " . $connection->error);
    }
    $rows = $result->num_rows;
    $isTranslation = false;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; ++$i) {
        $result->data_seek($i);

        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        //using strpos to find the first occurrence of a substring in a string
        $pos = strpos($row['English'],$translateWord);

        if ($pos !== false) {
            echo $row['Translation'] . "</br>";
            $isTranslation = true;
            break;
         } 
    }
    if (!$isTranslation)
                    echo "No translation can be found!</br>";
            }
    }
```

This is my code but it can only search for individual characters like `"How" -> "Como"` and if I try to search for more than one string it will give me `"No translation can be found!"`

Is there a way where I could search more than one string and output the character as a sentence?
Like search `"How are you"` and get `"Come son tu"`

I'm creating a lame translator for learning purposes haha.

Comment: You probably could make use of the [`IN()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in) function.

Comment: Focus of getting MySQL to fetch the right data, and PHP on displaying it.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I will give it a try thank you

Comment: You're welcome Toni. You know that if you happen to have found your own solution, Stack lets you post your own answer. I'd be happy to support it.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner for sure I'll post my solution when I get it :D

Comment: Ah, that's the spirit!! :D Another function that came to mind was SOUNDEX() and SOUNDS LIKE. Have a look in this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html and possibly other functions in that page.  Have a look at this website also http://www.mysqltutorial.org/ - It's a good place to learn tutorials also. I used it before and it's always helped me out.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I got the IN() function to work but it only returns the value of one string like Hello -> Como, when I try for more than one string it doesn't return anything.

Comment: You probably need to add to the WHERE clause using the `AND` operator. But I am not the guy for this; it's too complex a query for me.

Comment: I think you need to use LIKE in your query, same as search query to find matches words. is `$username` your table name or its the word you are searching for?

Comment: What happens when a word in english has two different words in the foreign language or vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put together some PHP that will attempt to process an entire input string (e.g. `How are you`). It converts the input string into an array of words, which is then used to generate an appropriate string for an `IN` expression (`How are you` => `'how','are','you'`) which is then added to the query. I've modified the query slightly to lower-case everything (so that `how` can match `How` or `HOW` or ...).

In the demo I've simulated a result set which you could obtain using `$result->fetch_all()`. The code loops through the list of words, attempting to match each one in the result array, and if it is found, trying to match the case (it deals with upper-case, capitalised and lower-case). Words not found in the result set are passed through untranslated.

```
$translateWord = 'How are you';
$words = explode(' ', $translateWord);
$list = implode(',', array_map(function ($word) { return "'" . strtolower(trim($word)) . "'"; }, $words));
$query = "SELECT LOWER(English) AS English, LOWER(Translation) AS Translation
          FROM $username
          WHERE LOWER(English) IN ($list)";
// query table
// $result = $connection->query($query);
// $rows = $result->fetch_all();
// simulated result
$rows = array(array('English' => 'how', 'Translation' => 'como'),
              array('English' => 'are', 'Translation' => 'son'),
              array('English' => 'you', 'Translation' => 'tu'));
$translation = array();
foreach ($words as $word) {
    if (($key = array_search(strtolower($word), array_column($rows, 'English'))) !== false) {
        // match case of result
        if (strtoupper($word) == $word) {
            $translation[] = strtoupper($rows[$key]['Translation']);
        }
        elseif (ucfirst($word) == $word) {
            $translation[] = ucfirst($rows[$key]['Translation']);
        }
        else {
            $translation[] = $rows[$key]['Translation'];
        }
    }
    else {
        // no match, leave alone
        $translation[] = $word;
    }
}
echo $translateWord . " => " . implode(' ', $translation);
```

Output:

```
How are you => Como son tu
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/JsDFE)

Comment: Thank you @Nick sorry for the late reply, I will try this out. :D

Comment: @Toni no worries - I hope it helps. Please note - you don't need to accept an answer until you've had a chance to try it out.